# Mysql select with conditional logic

Tags: mysql, select

I would like some help with the following: 
(my description will possibly seem weird, example picture below :)

in order to generate a graph, i want to select the 'days' based on a query generated by a form
(in this stage the query will only contain the 'from' and 'to' countries).

My problem is that i have no idea on how to make select use conditional logic so it picks 'days' from every 'item_id' that has a matching 'from' and 'to'.

(well the other problem is that i don't know any good keywords or actually how this is called, so please forgive me, i only did some blind googling and tried to find similar problems here)

[image: example]

Comment: could you give an example of your input (from to) and what you are expecting as a result ? (I don't really understand your question)

Comment: Why have you structure the table like this? Looks more like you're using the database as a key-value store to impose your own meta-database on top of it, which negates the purpose of having a relational database in the first place.

Comment: This is not a proper relation. Column `meta_value` mixes values of different types. Your table needs columns `id`, `origin`, `destination`, `date`, `days`, `userid` or similar to represent your information.

Comment: This is called [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), and is generally not a good way to store data in a RDBMS.

Comment: I think I recognise this table structure. Is it from the Sobi2 Joomla directory component?

Comment: If this table structure originates from some piece of software outside your control, it might make sense to include its name in the question title, so that others are more likely to find this question.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the responses! I will try the solutions you suggested in the weekend (or the next one if i can't) and update accordingly!

The database is from the wordpress 'formidablepro', its a survey plugin. So the database structure is predefined :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT days.meta_value
FROM tableName AS from_country,
     tableName AS to_country,
     tableName AS days
WHERE from_country.item_id = to_country.item_id
  AND from_country.item_id = days.item_id
  AND from_country.field_id = 90
  AND to_country.field_id = 93
  AND days.field_id = 251
```

You can add more restrictions if you want to filter by `from_country.meta_value` or similar. And you should replace `tableName` with the actual name of the table.

Think of `from_country`, `to_country` and `days` as three different pointers to rows in your table, or alternatively different variables taking values from your relation. You want all three of them to describe the same item, and you also want each of them to refer to the field associated with its name. This results in the conditions stated above.

You could even create a view, in order to access this badly designed table like a properly designed one:

```
CREATE VIEW viewName AS
SELECT item.item_id AS item_id,
       from_country.meta_value AS from_country,
       to_country.meta_value AS to_country,
       days.meta_value AS days
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT item_id FROM tableName) AS item
     LEFT JOIN tableName AS from_country
            ON (from_country.item_id = item.item_id AND
                from_country.field_id = 90)
     LEFT JOIN tableName AS to_country
            ON (to_country.item_id = item.item_id AND
                to_country.field_id = 93)
     LEFT JOIN tableName AS days
            ON (days.item_id = item.item_id AND
                days.field_id = 251)
```

This would create a view with four columns, from which you could simply select:

```
SELECT days FROM viewName WHERE from_country LIKE 'A%'
```

or whatever you want to select. Note that due to the left joins, missing values for some items will result in `NULL` values. This is in contrast to the query above, which will omit any item which doesn't have all three values specified. Use whatever is more appropriate in your situation.

Comment: It seem like your query is a lot simple than mine. Thumb up!