# SQL query, moving table field to column header

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way to retrieve data like this (first row is column header):

```
data   no    answer
data1  1     X1
data1  2     X2
data1  3     X3
data1  5     X5
data2  1     Y1
data2  2     Y2
data2  4     Y4
```

in format like this (again, first row is column header):

```
data   no1   no2   no3   no4   no5
data1  X1    X2    X3    null  X5
data2  Y1    Y2    null  Y4    null
```

using SQL query (in MySQL)?

Comment: This is called *pivoting*. MySQL doesn't support the PIVOT clause (which is what you could use if it did), but there are other methods. Have a look at this question: [SELECT distinct values for multiple rows of same ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419145/select-distinct-values-for-multiple-rows-of-same-id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQL does not have PIVOT functionality. So you will have to perform this another way.

Using `CASE` statements:

```
select data,
  MIN(CASE WHEN no = 1 THEN answer END) as no1,
  MIN(CASE WHEN no = 2 THEN answer END) as no2,
  MIN(CASE WHEN no = 3 THEN answer END) as no3,
  MIN(CASE WHEN no = 4 THEN answer END) as no4,
  MIN(CASE WHEN no = 5 THEN answer END) as no5
from test
group by data
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb5b7/1)

Comment: if I don't know how many numbers are there, how to do something like this exactly?

Comment: @zfm I don't have a MySQL instance to test with but you can se prepared statements.  See [Dynamic Pivot Tables](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html)