# Multiple mysql joins, how to combine these 2 select statments

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 select statements I would like to combine into one, though I really only need the info from one field in the second select statement(The field `data` from user_info_data). The fields I need are Firstname, lastname, email, course fullname, role, and the field `data` where fieldid = '15'. The first select statement will give me everything but the data field. And the second gives me everything but the course. I tried doing the second select statement similar to Role field but it complains about it returning more than one row. If I try and just use the course name without the fieldid='15' part, it brings up over 100k records(Each user shows up in each course and all their data).

Fields for tables:

```
user(id,auth,confirmed,policyagreed,username,password,idnumber,firstname,lastname,email,phone etc..)
user_info_data(id,userid,fieldid,data)
role(id,name,shortname,description,sortorder)
role_assignments(id,roleid,contextid,userid...)
context(id,contextlevel,instanceid,path,depth)
```

First statement:

```
SELECT user.firstname AS Firstname, user.lastname AS Lastname, user.email AS Email, course.fullname AS Course, role.name AS Role
FROM user AS user, course AS course,role,role_assignments AS asg
INNER JOIN context AS context ON asg.contextid=context.id   
WHERE context.contextlevel = 50
AND role.id=asg.roleid
AND user.id=asg.userid
AND context.instanceid=course.id
```

Output of first stament:

**Firstname     Lastname    Email   Course          Role**

John            Doe             john.doe@email.com  Course-Name Student

Second statement:

```
SELECT user.firstname AS 'First Name', user.lastname AS 'Last Name', user.email AS 'Email', user_info_data.data AS 'IBCLC Certified'
FROM user, user_info_data
WHERE user.id = user_info_data.userid
AND fieldid = '15'
```

Output of second stament:

**Firstname     Lastname    Email   IBCLC Certified**

John Doe    john.doe@email.com  Yes

***Desired Output:***

FirstName,LastName,Email,IBCLC Certified,Course,Role

Other select statement I tried: Brings up 9,494 records, but right now the field data where fieldid is 15 is a list of possible choices, could that be why?

```
SELECT user.firstname AS Firstname, user.lastname AS Lastname, user.email AS Email, userdata.data, course.fullname AS Course, role.name AS Role
FROM user AS user, course AS course, user_info_data AS userdata, role,role_assignments AS asg
INNER JOIN context AS context ON asg.contextid=context.id   
WHERE context.contextlevel = 50
AND userdata.fieldid = 15
AND role.id=asg.roleid
AND user.id=asg.userid
AND context.instanceid=course.id
```

Comment: On your select statements you have tried, why not just add 'role' to your FROM clause instead of using an embedded select statement?

Comment: @northpole That works, and brings the same results as the first statement, but I still don't know how to get the field `data` where fieldid=15,without having 113974 records; there should only be 94.

Comment: @johathan - are you saying there are only 94 rows where fieldid = 15?  That is the only thing you are reducing that table with.  Should it join to say users by userid?  Seems to me like you might be missing an additional where clause.

Comment: The tables are for a moodle database(216 tables) so i'm still a little confused at how they're all connected. The user_info_data, holds the data from the fields I added. And it keeps track of what data goes to which field through the fieldid, which connects to another table holding the actual fields(Employer,experience, etc) and since I only want the data from a certain field, I need to limit it to fieldid 15. There are only 94 users enrolled in all of the classes.

Comment: okay, so then most certainly you are missing some key additional where clauses here.  Looks like @MvG is helping you through that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `user_info_data` to your first request like this:

```
SELECT user.firstname AS Firstname,
       user.lastname AS Lastname,
       user.email AS Email,
       course.fullname AS Course,
       role.name AS Role,
       ibclcCert.data AS 'IBCLC Certified'
FROM user,
     course,
     role,
     role_assignments AS asg,
     context,
     user_info_data AS ibclcCert
WHERE context.contextlevel = 50
  AND role.id=asg.roleid
  AND user.id=asg.userid
  AND context.instanceid=course.id
  AND asg.contextid=context.id
  AND ibclcCert.userid = user.id
  AND ibclcCert.fieldid = '15'
```

I renamed the `user_info_data` table reference to something denoting the actual field, `ibclcCert` in this case. This renaming is a provision in case that you one day want to access more than one data field. When you do, you'd include the table multiple times, one for every field you need. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11332913/1468366) about how to deal with such data formats.

Comment: I tried it and received this error: #1054 - Unknown column 'user.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: Is there a column `user.id` in your database? Your second query uses one, but the error says there isn't one. Which is right?

Comment: Yes, there is. user "One record for each person" `1  id  bigint(10)   UNSIGNED  No  None  AUTO_INCREMENT` I got a similar error before when I was playing with roles, I switched the order I was using them in and it went away?

Comment: Any idea? Could I just select from a select statement with an alias then join it with the table? I would just add the user.id field to the first statement and then use the second inner join you provided above.

Comment: Okay, I tried what I commented on above. I did this: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT user.id,user.firstname AS Firstname, 
 user.lastname AS Lastname, 
 user.email AS Email, 
 course.fullname AS Course, 
 role.name AS Role
FROM user, 
 course,
 role,
 role_assignments AS asg
INNER JOIN context AS context ON asg.contextid=context.id   
WHERE context.contextlevel = 50
AND role.id=asg.roleid
AND user.id=asg.userid
AND context.instanceid=course.id) AS userInfo
INNER JOIN user_info_data ON userInfo.id = user_info_data.userid
WHERE user_info_data.fieldid = '15';` and it works, just brings in extra fields.

Comment: @Jonathan: OK, I found my error. Quoting from [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html): “the precedence of the comma operator is less than of INNER JOIN, CROSS JOIN, LEFT JOIN, and so on. If you mix comma joins with the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur.” Now I know why I hardly ever use INNER JOIN in my own queries. Edited the answer to avoid that.