# MySQL how to select multiple attributes from a Cartesian product?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get multiple attributes (e.g bedrooms, bathrooms, etc) from a few tables yes I can only seem to get one attribute with my current query.  What am I missing?

What I am ultimately trying to find is property_id's with 2 bathrooms and 2 bedrooms. In this case, my desired results are property id's 1 and 4.

Here's my example on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/?_escaped_fragment_=3/bd3c2/2/0#!2/7d18d/5)

Example tables:

```
property
--------
id 
1
2
3
4

attribute
---------
id name
1  bedrooms
2  bathrooms

attribute_value
---------------------
id attribute_id value
1  1            1
2  1            2
3  1            3
4  2            1
5  2            2
6  2            3

property_attributes
------------------------------
property_id attribute_value_id
1           2
1           5
2           2
2           4
3           1
3           4
4           2
4           5
```

This query can produce the results I want if I only want to see a query based on single attribute:

```
SELECT p.property_id
FROM property p
INNER JOIN property_attribute pa ON p.property_id = pa.property_id
INNER JOIN property_area pc ON p.property_id = pc.property_id
WHERE pa.attribute_value_id
IN (
SELECT av.attribute_value_id
FROM attribute_value av
INNER JOIN attribute a ON av.attribute_id = a.attribute_id
WHERE a.name like 'bedrooms' AND av.value like '2')
```

But what must I do to get results with more attributes (e.g. WHERE a.name like 'bathrooms' AND av.value like '2')?  If I add another subquery in the main where clause, it doesn't return any results.

/// **EDIT** ///

here is the solution that worked for me if anyone else winds up in such a situation:

```
SELECT p.property_id
FROM property p
INNER JOIN property_attribute pa ON p.property_id = pa.property_id
INNER JOIN property_attribute pa2 ON p.property_id = pa2.property_id
INNER JOIN property_attribute pa3 ON p.property_id = pa3.property_id
WHERE pa.attribute_value_id = 2 
AND pa2.attribute_value_id = 5
AND pa3.attribute_value_id = 7
```

This makes usage of a **self-join**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql select with conditional logic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332428/mysql-select-with-conditional-logic)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SELECT distinct values for multiple rows of same ID](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11419145/1468366)

Comment: @MvG, perhaps in the titular sense but as for the content of my question, I fail to see the similarities of it and the content of your suggested possible duplicates.

Comment: is this a multiple select attributes what types of things are these attribute / values associated with? products? What are you ultimately trying to find? a specific bathroom with a specific value that also has a 3-5 bedrooms and 2.5 baths? I understand the problem your having but it is hard to visualize the solution when your not giving much detail about what it is your trying to sort.

Comment: @RPM, you got it, I'm trying to find a property id's with say, 2 bathrooms and 2 bedrooms.

Comment: @Brandon This is actually a hard problem to solve. I know exactly what your trying to do though. It is a really interesting problem too. You see it everywhere on intelligent search engine sites. Your trying to find property's and there associated "products" with a specific value right? So you have a set of houses but all have different attributes. You want to find the houses where property(bathrooms) = 2 AND property(bedrooms) = 2. Why using like? That won't be an absolute value.

Comment: @RPM, you have the right idea of what I'm doing.  Check out my solution, it makes use of a self-join.  This does not scale well but there are other ways of achieving the answer such as using a count with a GROUP BY clause and a HAVING clause based on the count.

Comment: @Brandon Yes the group and having count(*) ( number of FACETS) or atttribute values whatever you call it. Have you considered a sub query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an awful lot of indirection in your schema. Is there any particular point why you need the `property_attribute` table? Do you expect a single attribute value to be shared by many properties?

In any case, here is the query for you. Very much in the spirit of the two [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11332428/1468366) [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11419145/1468366) I mentioned above.

```
SELECT property.property_id,
       bedrooms.value AS bedrooms,
       bathrooms.value AS bathrooms
FROM property,
     attribute AS bedrooms_attr,
     attribute_value AS bedrooms,
     property_attribute AS bedrooms_prop,
     attribute AS bathrooms_attr,
     attribute_value AS bathrooms,
     property_attribute AS bathrooms_prop
WHERE bedrooms_attr.name = 'bedrooms'
  AND bedrooms.attribute_id = bedrooms_attr.attribute_id
  AND bedrooms.attribute_value_id = bedrooms_prop.attribute_value_id
  AND bedrooms_prop.property_id = property.property_id
  AND bedrooms.value = 2
  AND bathrooms_attr.name = 'bathrooms'
  AND bathrooms.attribute_id = bathrooms_attr.attribute_id
  AND bathrooms.attribute_value_id = bathrooms_prop.attribute_value_id
  AND bathrooms_prop.property_id = property.property_id
  AND bathrooms.value = 2
```

Thanks for providing a fiddle with data to [play with](http://sqlfiddle.com/?_escaped_fragment_=3/bd3c2/2/0#!2/7d18d/37).

Comment: Yes, attributes will be shared by many properties.  The user can create whatever attributes they wish.  As for duplicates, ok maybe in spirit, but in the end, they did not help me at all.  I did however find some interesting ideas on this site that provided the ideas for a sufficient solution.  I'll post it above.  And yes, I had no clue sql fiddle existed, but thanks to you, it's now a standard tool.

Comment: @BrandonMinton, you seem to be talking about *attributes* shared by many properties, i.e. rows from the `attribute` table. That sharing makes perfect sense. I was referring to the sharing of *attribute values*, i.e. rows from the `attribute_value` table. That sharing I'd consider rather exotic, so that you might as well get rid of `property_attribute` and instead include the `property_id` in the `attribute_value` table. You could drop `attribute_value.id` and make `(property_id,attribute_id)` the combined primary key for `attribute_value`.

Comment: that is an excellent suggestion.  The term for this is normalizing correct?

Comment: @BrandonMinton, not sure about nomenclature. Normalizations are a pretty broad issue for database design. I see no normal form requirement which requires my approach. I believe an [ER model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model) would suggest it. I also believe that your [EAV model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) will likely violate [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), as different attributes might well have different domains. Christian Lindig wrote as much [in a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11332428/1468366).